# Has the account that customers use to log into Apple services always been known as an Apple ID?

Tags: apple-id, itunes-store

Has the account that customers use to log into Apple's various services always been known as an "Apple ID" - or was this originally known as a different name? As an example - when the iTunes Store originally launched, no reference is made as to the name of the account that customers used at the time to make purchases - and if a different name was used at some point in previous years, I haven't been able to find any references as to when it was renamed to "Apple ID".

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MobileMe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I still have .mac .me & .icloud addresses & also one from my own domain I first registered with iTunes in maybe 2005 & I don't remember it ever being called anything other than an Apple ID.

I just found this from when I joined the iTunes Store in 2005…

[image]

and this from .mac in 2004 [pictures are long gone, only text remains]

[image]

I don't have anything from earlier - I had an unfortunate break in my email storage in 2001, so have nothing older, but that probably covers it.

Comment: The original signup mail from January 2000: "Congratulations! You've successfully signed up for iTools, a new class of Internet services from Apple created exclusively for Mac users.  This email contains your account settings for iTools.  You may want to save this email for future reference."   So, Apple ID was not until sometime between then and 2004.